Use docker containers with podman
Is is possible to use existing docker containers with podman?
I am using regular rooted docker and have images and containers.
Now I would like to test rootless podman with those same containers, but it does not see them.
This is local test, so security is not a factor. User is sudo. It is Linux Mint/Ubuntu.

See Importing saved containers to Podman. The link goes to "Podman Desktop" documentation but instructions don't seem to be specific to that GUI tool.

TL;DR: You need to export/save the containers from docker to tar archives before you can import them with podman.

You cannot use podman to interact with docker containers.
You can export images from docker, load those images with podman, and then use them to create podman containers.
While you can use docker save and podman load to accomplish this task, it is perhaps more convenient to use skopeo, which allows you to perform the same thing in a single command:
skopeo copy docker-daemon:myimage:mytag containers-storage:myimage:mytag

For example, if I have:
$ docker image ls | grep traefik
traefik                               v2.11     c1ef9171e9d1   4 weeks ago     159MB
traefik/whoami                        latest    9807740ea1ff   9 months ago    6.61MB

Then I can copy the traefik/whoami:latest image from docker to podman like this:
skopeo copy docker-daemon:traefik/whoami:latest containers-storage:traefik/whoami:latest

And then start a container using that image:
podman run --rm -d -p 8080:80 traefik/whoami:latest


If you actually want to "migrate" a running container, it may be more appropriate to use docker export to export a container filesystem to a tar file, and then use podman import to create a new container image from that tar file (and then podman run to start a container from that image):
docker export my-running-container | podman import - my-image
podman run ... my-image


That answers my question, thanks. But on run I get "Error: no command or entrypoint provided, and no CMD or ENTRYPOINT from image". There I assume it may be --entrypoint missing, but if I set from docker container "/entrypoint.sh apache2-foreground", again "Error: crun: executable file not found in $PATH". Container is Nextcloud. I understand that may be a different issue, just to note that export-import is not simple.
